# Calculate Player WinLoss Percentage

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to render a win loss chart based on player performance, I was hoping someone will have experience with similar calculations.

So here is what I have:

```
public class Player
{
   public virtual bool IsWinner { get; set; }
}

//Sample list
var listOfPlayers = new List<Player>
                                  {
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = true },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = false },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = false },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = true },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = true },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = false },
                                      new Player{ IsWinner = true }
                                  };
```

The players list comes from Database and basically each player in the list belongs to a different match.

So I have this function where I am supplying the list of players and the respective index in the list:

So lets say for example that at index 2 I have one win and 2 losses, because I am rendering a chart I need this function to return a double that will represent the win/loss percentage so it will have (player won 25%of matches 0-3)

```
public double CalculateWinLossPercentage(List<Player> listOfPlayers,int index)
{
    double winpercentage = null;
    //calculate win percentage base on the total list of players 
    //and the current index in list
    return winpercentage;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How do we know which records correspond to which player?  Right now your example appears to have seven different players, each with a single win or loss.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just keeping an int totalWins and int totalLosses, updating them after each match, and doing basic math?

Comment: one win 2 losses, 25%, 0-3 your sample math makes no sense

Comment: I apologize the representation is a bit misleading, initially all I have is a player ID, the way data is organized in database is that players are saved multiple times in Player table as one player might belong to different matches. Initially I have a player GUIID and I query the Player table for all player with a specific GUIID, it returns me a list of players and each of them has won/lost for a specific Match. So I need to get a percentage won base on the index whic really is the match. In this exampel 7 Matches and I need win % based on supplied match (3 for example) .

Comment: Makes less sense. A player has a GUIID but a search on specific GUIID will return a list of players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public double CalculateWinLossPercentage(List<Player> listOfPlayers,int index)
{
    int count = listOfPlayers.GetRange(0, index + 1).Count(p => p.IsWinner);
    return ((double)count)/(index+1);
}
```

This will return the percentage as a double (number between 0 and 1).
Also, in your example, with index = 2, the correct result would be 33.3%, not 25%.